# Is Null In where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

which one  is better in Where  clause?

```
(cola  =@var)  OR (cola IS NULL AND colb=@var)

ISNULL(cola,colb)=@var
```

We have Index On cola and colb If it matters

i like use second code but idk if it is good .
ISNULL(cola,colb)=@var
it is smaller code!
table has more than 400m records , so  performance is all  matters...

Comment: Have you looked into a union?

Comment: `ISNULL(cola,colb)` is bad because it prevents the use of any indexes covering the columns

Comment: @shawnt00 how would a UNION help here? It would result either in the same execution plan, if the query optimizer is very smart, or two queries instead of one.

Comment: It was always a technique in the past to get around a table scan. I don't know if that applies here.

Comment: @shawnt00  u mean i write union  cola=@var and colb=@var?
 it is worse , i guess

Comment: "Smaller code", especially when SQL is involved, rarely means "faster". A `WHILE` is often "smaller" to write than an rCTE, which is smaller to write than an inline tally, however, a Tally is *significantly* faster than an rCTE, and an rCTE often significantly faster (again) than a `WHILE`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think shawnt00 means to do the whole query twice `SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE cola = @var UNION ALL SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE cola IS NULL AND colb = @var` which is a legitimate mitigation around the fact that often the compiler does not do two index seeks and instead favours a full scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISNULL(cola,colb)=@var` is very bad, especially when 400M rows are involved, because it prevents the use of any indexes that cover the columns. The database will have to calculate the result for all 400M rows. With an index, it would quickly locate just the rows that match the condition in `O(log(N))` operations. To do so it would have to read the entire data page each time into RAM, polluting buffers with data that isn't really needed.

Indexes on the other hand contain just values of the indexed columns which means a lot more records can be kept in memory. Not only are fewer operations needed, they're typically performend in memory. Even when index pages have to be loaded from disk, a lot less IO is needed.

If the query optimizer is *very* smart it could expand this into `(cola  =@var)  OR (cola IS NULL AND colb=@var)`. I wouldn't count on it just to save a few keystrokes though.

Indexes are created from the actual table contents and can't be used to accelerate searches on function results. Queries that try to filter on function results are invariably slow, unless the query optimizer somehow manages to convert them to a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) (searchable, indexable) form. Queries that can't be converted like this are called non-SARGable.

You can create indexes on persisted computed columns though. A persisted computed column is effectively a normal column whose value is updated automatically when its sources change. This can be useful if, eg you want to filter rows based on a JSON attribute, the month of a date or some other value that can be calculated.

Comment: *"You can create indexes on persisted computed columns though."* This implies that you *can't* create indexes on non-persisted columns, which isn't the case.

Comment: colB =@var OR COALESCE(COLA, @var) = @var

Comment: @PowerMouse that's as bad as `ISNULL(cola,colb)=@var` because it compares the result of a function with a value. This can't use indexes